# Uncaught ReferenceError: UserApi is not defined

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, webview

Am loading a web page in an android web view.I have included .js file as script.I have test it almost all version of android. But the page is not loading in iBALL Slid 3G (version 5.1.1 )
I have compare the configuration with other working device its is lenovo 7000 (version 5.1) i found that its Android System WebView is an older version.even in updating this its still not working my js code is include

```
(function() {
    window.UserApi = {
        url: URL + '/api/login.php',
        user_id: 0,
        user_name: '',
        file_upload_url: URL + '/upload.php',
        init: function() {},
        onSuccess: function(reponse) {
            UserApi.function1();
        },
        function1: function() {},
        function2: function() {},
        functionN: function() {}
    };
    UserApi.init();
})();
```

Is there any issue with the js code .This is working in almost all devices.
If any have any idea please share

Comment: In isolation the code you've posted works absolutely fine: https://jsfiddle.net/RoryMcCrossan/6per084r/. Are you sure this is a representative version of your production code? Have you tried `window.UserApi.init();` just in case any of the webviews have some odd JS implementation where `window` is not the top level object.

Comment: yes i have written code in this manner like including functions in UserApi.It is working in all device expect this perticular product iBall slid 3G